# Pattern Matching with dynamic matcher

Tags: java, regex, regular-language

Sample input string : `Customer ${/xml:Name} has Ordered Product ${/xml:product} of ${/xml:unit} units.`

i able to find get strings that match ${ ...... } using `"\\$\\{.*?\\}"`

I resolve the value for string from xml and now i have to replace the value back in input string.

i am using this method,

```
Pattern MY_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\$\\{.*?\\}");
Matcher m = MY_PATTERN.matcher(inputstring);
while (m.find()) {
String s = m.group(0); // s is ${/xml:Name}

// escaping wild characters
s = s.replaceAll("${", "\\$\\{");  // s is \$\{/xml:Name}
s = s.replaceAll("}", "\\}"); // s is  \$\{/xml:Name\}

Pattern inner_pattern = Pattern.compile(s);
Matcher m1 = inner_pattern.matcher(inputstring);
name = m1.replaceAll(xPathValues.get(s));
}
```

but i get error at `s = s.replaceAll("${", "\\$\\{");` i get Pattern Syntax Exception

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
s = s.replaceAll("${", "\\$\\{");  // s is \$\{/xml:Name}
s = s.replaceAll("}", "\\}"); // s is  \$\{/xml:Name\}
```

You can use it without regex method `String#replace(string)`:

```
s = s.replace("${", "\\$\\{").replace("}", "\\}"); // s is \$\{/xml:Name\}
```

Answer (score 2):

You must escape the `{` too, try `$\\{`

Answer (score 1):

It's because you could have a regexp like`a{1,4}` means to match a,aa,aaa,aaaa so a times 1 to 4, java tries to interpret your regexp like this, therefore try escaping the `{`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you must escape the {, but I would rather capture what's inside the braces:

```
Pattern MY_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\$\\{/xml:(.*?)\\}");
Matcher m = MY_PATTERN.matcher(inputstring);
while (m.find()) {
    name = m.group(1); // s is Name
    ...
}
```